# std::bind parameter to member function without object

Tags: c++, std-function, stdbind

I need to bind one parameter to class member function.
Something like this:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct test
{
    void func(int a, int b)
    {
        std::cout << a << " " << b << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    typedef void (test::*TFunc)(int);
    TFunc func = std::bind(&test::func, 1, std::placeholders::_1);
}
```

But in this case I have compilation error

```
error: static assertion failed: Wrong number of arguments for pointer-to
-member
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't expect the object generated by `std::bind` to be convertible to a plain member function pointer...

Comment: If you're looking for a way to essentially define a member function outside the class definition, then this simply can't be done.  You can only add an overload to the class or define a free function.

Answer (score 5):

`std::bind` does not yield a member function pointer, but it can produce a `std::function` object that you can use later:

```
::std::function< void (test *, int)> func = std::bind(&test::func, std::placeholders::_1, 1, std::placeholders::_2);
test t{};
func(&t, 2);
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but your decision slightly differ from my requirements

Comment: @tenta4 the return type of `std::bind` is always an object of (some) class type. There is no conversion from that to pointer-to-member-function. For one thing there is nowhere for the bound `int` to go.